# jQuery Removes Selection from List

Tags: jquery

I am updating an application that is using some jQuery function which I am not an expert.  The following code is taking a selection from a list and adding it to a selected list and removing it from the original list.

```
$('#addCat').click(function() {  
  return !$('#laborCategoryID option:selected').remove().appendTo('#selLaborCategoryID');  
 });
```

My question is the client no longer wants the selection removed from the list so they can select it multiple times.  Can I do this by just removing the remove() from this code or is there more involvement?

Comment: Can't you just try it?

Comment: LOL, of course, but when working with government applications you tend to not just try things.  It didn't change anything, it still removed the selection from the original list.  :)

Comment: Well, I am not suggesting to try it on the production server, I mean try it out on a test file, and see if it has the desired behaviour.

Comment: _"Can I do this by just removing the replace() from this code "_ Did you mean remove the `remove()` from the code? I see no `replace()`

Comment: Correct, my bad.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery clone() function.

You can refer this link.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

This will clone one div into another. Hope it will help.